# Can I get the url for managing an envelope from the Docusign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm able to create an envelope with the API which returns the envelopeId which looks like:

13f23354-7eee-41d3-897a-c1353a1e465c

When I navigate to docusign in my browser and open the envelope the url is:
https://na2.docusign.net/MEMBER/EnvelopeSetup.aspx?ti=ad05458248c54654a16a54195bf72ffe

I don't see what that "ad05458248c54654a16a54195bf72ffe" id is. I've tried every envelope API in the documentation (many don't make sense, but I tried them anyways):

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}  
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/email_settings
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/notification
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/templates
```

But that id isn't anywhere.

Is there a way to retrieve that URL id? and/or is there another way I can get the url for the envelope?

Answer (score 1):

The ID that appears as part of any URL when you're using the DocuSign web console is an internal ID -- you cannot use it with the API in any way.  The Envelope ID value that DocuSign returns in response to the "Create Envelope" API request is the ID that you'll want to use with any API request that requires an Envelope ID.

It's not exactly clear to me what you mean by "[url for] *managing an envelope*" -- but I'd suggest you explore the following operations in the [DocuSign REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf):

- Post Envelope Correction (page 146)
- Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information (page 137)
- Post Sender View (page 149)

(I'd guess that "Post Envelope Correction" is likely what you're after.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I want the url so that, once I'm done creating an envelope with the API, I can provide the user a url so he/she can navigate to it right away. I was hoping there would be a way to do that.