# How to get a URL to an envelope to send via SMS?

Tags: docusignapi

I noticed that DocuSign can now [send a notification to sign an envelope via SMS](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-sms-delivery?_ga=2.22901759.577615980.1608147428-408385905.1608147428). We would like to send the link through our own SMS account so our clients know that it's coming from us.  [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738785/get-envelope-url) have been asked in the past on this subject, but now that DocuSign has their own SMS notification service that includes the link I'm hoping this is something that we can get from the API. The sandbox account and the API docs don't appear to be supporting this yet, so maybe I have to wait. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Dave, this is a new feature and we'll be documenting it very soon.
This feature is not enabled by default in our developer accounts, and requires that you contact the DocuSign team (either through support or your account manager) to enable it for you. This is a premium feature in production, but even in the developer account, where it's free, you would need to have it activated for you.
Here is something to help you while we work on the official documentation:
(this is a snippet of the JSON needed for this feature if you have it enabled on your account)

```
{
   "signers":[
      {
         "routingOrder":1,
         "name":"John Smith",
         "email":"John.Smith@Acme.com",
         "deliveryMethod":"email",
         "recipientId":"1",
         "additionalNotifications":[
            {
               "secondaryDeliveryMethod":"SMS",
               "phoneNumber":{
                  "countryCode":1,
                  "number":"4445556666"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, however I really don't want DocuSign to send the SMS message. We already have an ongoing SMS conversation with our clients and would like to send a link to the envelope directly so it's part of the same conversation. I just use the API to generate envelopes from templates and send them, and would like to use DocuSign to handle the rest.

Comment: oh, sure, you can do that. That was always a possibility. The issue is the URL has to be to your server and your server would then generate embedded signing and redirect the user. You cannot embed a fixed DocuSign URL in your own text message.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing embedded signing since it's just extra steps, but it looks like that's the direction I need to go. Thanks!

Comment: Is this feature available when creating an envelope from a template? I added the additionalNotifications property the signers element and it didn't work. I didn't get any errors, but only received the notification via email.

Comment: do you have the feature enabled in your account? can you do it via UI? I believe you can use it from templates, but you would first need to enable it by contacting us directly.

Comment: I already requested the feature and it is enabled in my sandbox account. I can send it successfully from the UI.

Comment: I just realized I put the wrong info in my comment from earlier today. I added the additionalNotifications array to the *templateRoles* element. Signers is for creating an envelope without a template.

Comment: Im not sure you can set up templates where there's a role for an SMS, that may not exist yet, what I meant is that you can have a hardcoded number. I'll check on this internally and reply back here.

Comment: I'm further along now. I didn't have the SMS option on for the client role. I added it, but now I'm getting an error that the country code is missing. I can hard-code the number in the template role, but that doesn't help me since the signer will be different each time.

Comment: you must have country code, but I think you get the error on an empty number, right? I wonder if you need to overwrite the recipient with a PUT call (updateRecipients) that's not normally needed for templates. Like I said, I'm checking on this feature internally, that's new territory that you're covering here...

Comment: I heard back from the go live team and they said there appears to be a bug, and had the same recommendation: 
"I started researching this issue this afternoon and may have found a bug in the composite template call that does not allow the phone number to be set. I am still experimenting with workarounds. One thing that I think will work is to make the template call as normal but set the status to created."